# Print n choose k combination algorithm using recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, combinations

This must be a classic interview question, however, I'm having a problem understanding it.

Below is my implementation in Python and if you run it, it's only printing `ab, ac, ad`. It doesn't go to the `'b' (bc, bd)` level.

```
def Print_nCk (the_list, k, str_builder, used):
    if len(str_builder) == k:
        print str_builder
        return 
    else:
        for i in xrange(len(the_list)):
            if used[i] !=True:
                str_builder+=the_list[i]
                used[i] = True
                Print_nCk(the_list, k, str_builder, used)
                str_builder = str_builder[:-1]


Print_nCk(['a','b','c','d'], 2, "",[False,False,False,False])
```

The right answer is `ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd` when above line is passed.

I know the right implementation from here without using `used` param (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/) but 
my question is what is wrong is my implementation?

Can you shed some light on it?

To debug, I printed out "used" every time. The `used` param becomes (True, True, True, True) after printing "ad" then it doesn't go deeper than that. What's the smart way to fix the `used`, if I insist on using `used`?

Comment: By the way, `>>> [''.join(c) for c in combinations(['a','b','c','d'], 2)] ;
['ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd', 'cd']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to **unset `used[i]`** when you **backtrack**:

```
def Print_nCk (the_list, k, str_builder, used):
    if len(str_builder) == k:
        print str_builder
        return
    else:
        for i in xrange(len(the_list)):
            if used[i] != True:
                str_builder += the_list[i]
                used[i] = True
                Print_nCk(the_list, k, str_builder, used)
                str_builder = str_builder[:-1]
                used[i] = False


Print_nCk(['a','b','c','d'], 2, "",[False,False,False,False])
```

In your current implementation, you set `used[i]` to `True` from the moment you *pick* the `i` as value. If however later, you decide to pick another branch, you should do the bookkeeping correctly and thus unset the `used[i]`.

Note that now `"ab"` and `"ba"` will be generated. You thus **generate combinations with symmetry**. If you do not want that, you can use an **additional parameter**. That makes sure that you do not **use an index lower than the previously picked one**:

```
def Print_nCk (the_list, k, str_builder, used, prev = 0):
    if len(str_builder) == k:
        print str_builder
        return
    else:
        for i in xrange(prev,len(the_list)):
            if used[i] != True:
                str_builder += the_list[i]
                used[i] = True
                Print_nCk(the_list, k, str_builder, used, i+1)
                str_builder = str_builder[:-1]
                used[i] = False


Print_nCk(['a','b','c','d'], 2, "",[False,False,False,False])
```

Nevertheless, this more or less defeats the purpose of using a "used" array. You can simply use the `prev`:

```
def Print_nCk (the_list, k, str_builder, prev = 0):
    if len(str_builder) == k:
        print str_builder
        return
    else:
        for i in xrange(prev,len(the_list)):
            str_builder += the_list[i]
            Print_nCk(the_list, k, str_builder, i+1)
            str_builder = str_builder[:-1]


Print_nCk(['a','b','c','d'], 2, "")
```

This then prints:

```
>>> Print_nCk(['a','b','c','d'], 2, "")
ab
ac
ad
bc
bd
cd
```

Comment: This prints `da, db, dc` too.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: and that's now fixed :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It's funny to see how fast this uv dv changes according to your edit :)

Comment: @ToussaintLouverture You should accept this answer because it answers your question. But for a cleaner approach, do take a look at my answer.

Comment: Any idea what the time complexity is here? Nice code @WillemVanOnsem!

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to the party, but I think you should take more advantage of recursion. There's no need to pass any superfluous arguments.

Here's a simpler approach:

```
def Print_nCk(the_list, size):
    combs = []
    if size == 1: # the base case
        return the_list

    for i, c in enumerate(the_list[:-size + 1]):
        for sub_comb in Print_nCk(the_list[i + 1:], size  - 1): # generate and return all sub-combos of size - 1
            combs.append(c + sub_comb) # for each sub-combo, add the sizeth (or n - sizeth) character

    return combs
```

This approach generates combinations of `size - 1` and combines them with the `size`th character.

For size-2 combinations:

```
>>> Print_nCk(['a','b','c','d'], 2)
['ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd', 'cd']
```

For size-3 combinations:

```
>>> Print_nCk(['a','b','c','d'], 3)
['abc', 'abd', 'acd', 'bcd']
```